# Somehow move the + , so it will not stand so odd

Tags: html, signature

How can I make the + image in this table go a bit higher, so it will not stand so odd? I do not want to use text, because of font issues. I tried aligning it, but it doesn't help. I want to use this as an email signature, so there are a lot of comparability problems, that eliminate certain options.

```html
<table width="442" height="144" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="224" rowspan="5"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/SQR.png~original" alt="" width="148" height="148" align="left"/></th>
      <th width="38"><a href="http://benjaminjayshand.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/WP-i.png~original" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></a></th>
      <td width="168" height="29"><a href="http://benjaminjayshand.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/WP.png~original" width="140" height="10" alt=""/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="38"><a href="http://designtel.co/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/WB2-i.png~original" width="15" height="13" alt=""/></a></th>
      <td height="29"><a href="http://designtel.co/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/WB2.png~original" width="88" height="10" alt=""/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="38"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/benjaminjayshand/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/IST1-i.png~original" width="15" height="13" alt=""/></a></th>
      <td height="29"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/benjaminjayshand/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/IST1.png~original" width="94" height="10" alt=""/></a> <img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/PLUS.png~original" alt="" width="5" height="5" align="baseline"/> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/designtel/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/IST2.png~original" width="51" height="10" alt=""/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="38"><a href="mailto:info@benjaminjayshand.com"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/EML-i.png~original" width="15" height="12" alt=""/></a></th>
      <td height="29"><a href="mailto:info@benjaminjayshand.com"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/EML.png~original" width="136" height="10" alt=""/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="38"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/TEL-i.png~original" width="15" height="9" alt=""/></th>
      <td height="29"><img src="http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee449/benjaminjayshand/TEL.png~original" width="62" height="7" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
-
```

Comment: you can use css property margin-bottom on that element

Comment: You can't reliably use CSS margins in emails.  Webmail strips a lot of that, and certain desktop email clients (ahem...Outlook) are even more limited.

Comment: then you can always make higher picture..

Answer (score 0):

I started a long post, splitting the cell into 3 columns and setting the rest of the rows to have a `colspan="3"` and then realized the simple answer - just make the plus sign image 10 pixels tall.  Center the existing image inside that larger canvas.